# Two reactions that catalyze each other

Tags: catalysis

Is there an example of two reactions that catalyze one another? More than two is also helpful, but I guess it will be hard to find one.

By "catalyze one another", I mean that one of the products of the first reaction acts as a catalyst for the second reaction.

Comment: Reactions do not catalyze reactions.

Comment: Could we please reopen this question? It seems pretty clear what the OP is asking.

Comment: I agree.  There has to be more than the magnesium nitride/boron nitride thing I stumbled upon a while back.

Answer (score 2):

[An early synthesis of borazon from hexagonal boron nitride](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_nitride) would be one possible example.  When other approaches did not work, Robert H. Wentorf Jr. added magnesium and voila!  The magnesium had reacted with some of the hexagonal nitride to form $\ce{Mg3N2}$, and the latter then catalyzed the hexagonal to cubic conversion.  (Today other methods have taken over.)